# Running Azure application on a local development environment got extreamly slow

Tags: visual-studio-2008, azure

Problem:
I have a Azure project.
The problem is that when I run the application it takes like 10-15 minutes to actually open the page in browser. The page & debugging works normaly.

Project:
using VS 2008 Version 9.030729.1 SP

Solution (7 projects) 
• Hitrarisma (Azure configuration project)
HitraPisma.DataAccess (c# class)
HitraPisma.WebRole (asp.net mvc 1.0)
HitraPisma.WorkerRole
PrintPreview  (c# dll)
StorageClient  (c# dll)
TestPrintPreview (c# windows test app for testing PrintPreview dll)

CPU is low, memory is plenty - what could be wrong?

I guess the azure Service configuration is fine if everything works.

Any pointers are more than welcome.

Tnx,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have upgraded my Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio to November 2009 edition and the problems have dissapeared. This package includes Azure SDK.

You should know that there are quite a few object model changes, so I had to "rewrite" some code.

Regards,
Tom